# iOS/Android/Windows private app stores - limit app visibility

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, app-store

I've been looking in to distributing private apps across iOS, Android and Windows Phone. Each of these offer their own implementation of a private app store/channel. However, this seems to be tailored to the situation where it is an employer distributing apps to an employee and doesn't want to restrict the availability of apps to certain users.

Is it possible to do this using any of the native app stores or do I have to rely on a 3rd party service for this functionality? For example, If I have two apps which I want to privately distribute, one available to everyone, and one restricted by some criteria (users who are a member of a specific group or assigned a certain role/permission)?

Comment: For iOS this is not allowed at all. You can only use the InHouse distribution, which accourding to the license allows you to only distribute to company employees. Also this distribution will not use the AppStore, but is just some hosted files on a secure website.

Comment: So third party services that offer this are the best way to go? Out of curiosity, does Android/Windows Phone allow this?

Comment: For iOS you can only use the InHouse distribution, whether you are using a third party service or not. **But** be aware you are only allowed to distribute the app to employees of the company that is registered for the Enterprise license. I have now idea about Android or Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone, 3rd party distributors aside, I think you have three possible ways to distribute your software. Not sure if you are happy with any of then, though.

- Become trusted distributor by applying for `code signing certificate` from Microsoft. Symantec will verify that yes, you are actually "you" and provide you with the enterprise/code  signing certificate. After obtaining cert you need to sign XAPs you are distributing and provide your target audience with so called `application enrollment token` (via email or download link). User must first install the token, then they can install any package signed by you. Certification process is not free and it can take some time. Good thing is that then you are free to distribute your apps as you please, to whom you please.
- Publish your software in public Store and just require login credentials. This might be easiest but publishing process per update can take up to five days and MS needs some test login before they publish it.
- Publish your software in public Store as Beta version. In beta MS verification process in faster and you can limit people (up to 10000) that can download the application. Bad thing is that audience is identified with email address that must be connected to their Microsoft/Live accounts.